# Swagger for ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework 4.7.2) MVC-Only Application (without WebApi and Core)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

regarding to the following github-thread https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5722 it should be possible to document controllers derived from System.Web.MVC.Controller with Swashbuckle and NSwag.

But I was not able to create a working example, so my question: can this be done?

What I have tried:

1. Open Visual Studio 2019 and start the wizard to create a new "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)"
2. On the next wizard-page Select .NET Framework Version 4.7.2
3. On the next wizard-page named "Create a new ASP.NET Web Application" select the template

   - "MVC" - (A project template for creating ASP.NET MVC applications. ASP.NET MVC allows you to build applications suing the Model-View-Controller architecture. [...])
4. Open the project "Properties". Switch to tab "Build". Check "XML documentation file" checkbox.
5. Do a right-click on the project in the solution-explorer and select context-menu-entry "Manage NuGet Packages..." and install "Swashbuckle"-package
6. Start debugging and browse to http://localhost:<Port>/Swagger

The autogenerated HomeController contains 3 default actions "Index, About and Contact".
I added some custom XML-Documentation to this actions - why don't I see HomeController in the swagger-ui?
Is there anything I have forgotten to configure?

Comment: Did you try to add one more controller besides the Home one?